# protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)

Tags: c#, function

I am developing an application in visual studio 2012. I have used a function:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case (Keys.Enter):
                    {
                        btnok.PerformClick();
                        return true;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

I want to know

1. Is it a built in function?
2. What is the purpose of the input parameter 'ref Message msg' in the first line?
3. what is the purpose of the statement:

   ```
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
   ```

Any body please explain.

Comment: On what class is the method defined?

Comment: Is what a built-in function? Your method as written is entirely pointless... you have a switch statement but don't take any action in it, and then you delegate to the base implementation. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am defining it a user defined class 'SaleOrder' which is inherited from 'Form' Class

Comment: [C# Basics / Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_classes.htm) makes for some good reading `Ikram Khan`

Comment: @JonSkeet I was using just a sample code. Now I have done it a bit meaning full

Comment: It is actually working well

Comment: @JonSkeet Unreachable `break` would be a warning only, but it should be fixed, of course.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: My mistake - that surprises me though. Comment deleted. Ick, mind you - why use a switch here at all?

Comment: On a side note, you can click on "btnok" when the Enter key is pressed by selecting the Form and setting its `AcceptButton` property to "btnok"...no code necessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, a `switch` statement with only one switch section which carries only a single `case` label, is silly. An `if` is much simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [`Form.ProcessCmdKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of the Windows Forms framework.

What it does:

> The ProcessCmdKey method overrides the base
>   ContainerControl.ProcessCmdKey implementation to provide additional handling of main menu command keys and MDI accelerators.
>   For information about trapping keystrokes, see "How to trap keystrokes in controls by using Visual C#" and "How to trap keystrokes in .NET controls by using Visual Basic .NET" in the Microsoft Knowledge Base at http://support.microsoft.com.

> what is the purpose of the statement: `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData)`

The syntax `base.Method()` means you're calling the `Method` defined in the base class closest to the current class in the hierarchy tree.

Since your class derives directly from `Form`, `base.ProcessCmdKey` will call the method defined by `Form` (the method cited above).

I strongly suggested reading: [base (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: Could you tell what is the purpose of the statement: return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

Comment: @IkramKhan Read [`base` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx). It calls the base class implementation of this virtual method (in a non-virtual way, so no infinite recursion), and returns its return value.

Comment: @IkramKhan I've added that to my answer